# What should be the impact of thread and sessions over paypal mechanism in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, session, paypal

Now a days i am looking for the perfect time estimation for the asp.net 4.0 with c# integration. since workflow is while user subscribing on the site, he should pay for subscription. Well this is the normal usecase now a days. but how developers manages the sessions and threading while performing the payment transactions.

In fact i don not have much knowledge about threading and session and suddenly i have the task to build this mechanism. well, how to manage all this ? so that transaction is more secure from our side. (sure paypal has taken care. and how many ways we can integrate paypal with asp.net application ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a "script" that handles a url from paypal.

Ex. When user payment is confirmed paypal sends info on www.yousite.com/paypalhandler.aspx

This info contains userId etc etc. And now the script makes the necessary updates to your db.

Comment: Thanks buddy, may i use javascript or something simillar like that ? do i need to use something like thread safe to manage this as per user ? because it may happens number of users concurrently subscribing to the site. and each subscription deals with paypal getway for performing the payment in admin accoun.

Comment: Iv'e done this with c# only if you get a paypal sandbox account you can get an example file to see how this works. Also you don't need to mess with threads, just make sure you don't try to update the same row from multiple users.